# Display every day in a month in each rows of the gridview

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to display every day of the month in a gridview?The days will be based in the current month so I think it is auto generated can somebody help me?

Comment: It's called a Calendar control.

Comment: Not really calendar control becuase I want to display each day of the month in the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exec the below sql query and bind it to the gridview in code behind

```
Declare @Days Table (DateField datetime)

Declare @CurrentDate datetime
Declare @EndDate datetime

Set @CurrentDate = '01-Nov-2007'
Set @EndDate = '30-Nov-2007'

While @CurrentDate <= @EndDate
  Begin
     Insert Into @Days Values(@CurrentDate)
     Set @CurrentDate = DateAdd(d,1,@CurrentDate)
  End 

Select convert(char(2),DateField,103) From @Days
```

--------- If you need solution in c# then ---------

```
 using System.Linq;
  public IEnumerable<DateTime> DateRange(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, toDate.Subtract(fromDate).Days + 1)
                         .Select(d => fromDate.AddDays(d));
    }
        IEnumerable<DateTime> dates;
        dates = DateRange(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(10));
```

dates member will contain all the dates between the given  range, this you can add to datatable and bind it to Gridview.

Comment: how can I bind those sql querry in gridview sir? Can you give me an example?thanks

Comment: can somebody help me with this problem?